# How can I copy files from the GitLab Runner helper container to the build container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

### Set up

I set up GitLab Runner with a KubernetesExecutor and want to create a custom helper image which adds some extra files to the build container.

The current set up is quite basic:

- A `Dockerfile`, which adds some files (`start.sh` and `Dockerfile`) into the container.
- A `start.sh` file which is present in the helper image. This should be executed when the helper is run.

### Code

**start.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

printenv > /test.out  # Check whether the script is run.
cp /var/Dockerfile /builds/Dockerfile  # Copy file to shared volume.

exec "$@"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-latest

ADD templates/Dockerfile /var/Dockerfile
ADD start.sh /var/run/start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/var/run/start.sh"]
```

The shared volume between the containers is: `/builds`. As such, I'd like to copy `/var/Dockerfile` to `/builds/Dockerfile`.

### Problem

I can't seem to find a way to (even) run `start.sh` when the helper image is executed. Using  `kubectl exec -it pod-id -c build bash` and `kubectl exec -it pod-id -c helper bash`, I verify whether the files are created. When I run `start.sh` (manually) from the latter command, the files are copied. However, neither `/test.out` nor `/builds/Dockerfile` are available when logging in to the helper image initially.

### Attempts

- I've tried setting up a different `CMD` (`/var/run/start.sh`), but it seems like it simply doesn't run the `sh` file.